# Reading and Parsing data from Firestore--- Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
    final database = Provider.of<Database>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<List<Job>>(
      stream: database.jobsStream(),
        builder: (context, snapshot),{
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          final jobs = snapshot.data;
          final children = jobs.map((job) => Text(job.name)).toList();
          return ListView(childrem: children);
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
```

getting error Build Context cant be assigned to the parameter type Widget(build Context,AsyncSnapshot....

Comment: wat is the full error

Comment: gotcha by mistake put the cooma(",") in the builder code line